# Is boost::graph the right tool for this task?

Tags: c++, boost, tree, graph-theory

I have the following simplified situation:

I need to create a tree like the following one:

[image: tree]

I start at one node with a score of 3. From this node I calculate all possible next nodes which have the score 4, 6, 5 and 7. In the next step I only want to consider the two nodes with the highest score, in our case 6 and 7. From these two nodes I again calculate all possible next nodes. The highest score of all the next nodes are 12 and 13 so in the next step, I only want to consider these two nodes as my next start point. This means all nodes from the previous score 6 nodes are ignored from now on.

And so on...

I have no idea about graph theory right now (but I guess I have to do some research)

I looked for some libraries which might help me implement this in C++. I came across boost::graph which looks promising at a first glance. Downside is, it looks also also quite complex.

My question is:

1. Do you think boost::graph can be easily used to implement a tree like this? Is it worth spending some days trying to lean boost::graph, or is it not the right library for me.
2. Is there a better library? I quite like boost and have used it a lot, but not the graph library of it.

I think my requirements are

1. calculation of my nodes is quite expensive, therefore I need a tree/graph which saves the *"score"* of each node and can be easily extended later.
2. it should be possible to simply say _"from now on let's ignore those nodes" and focus on those two best ones.
3. I need to somehow easily be able to get access to the *"end of my tree"* at each step, so that I know which nodes are the current nodes I have to calculate the next possible nodes.
4. to calculate the score of my next nodes I need to be able to easily follow the tree back to its root (I do not only need the previous score but more information. My implementation would somehow require that each node is an object and a score and I need to have access to the members of those objects as well as to the score). This means I need to be able to reconstruct my way through the tree.

Note:

I guess it should be a kind of standard problem for graph theory. But right now I do not really know where to start my research. If you have any good literature, papers, descriptions, key words for google, for this problem please tell me.

**Edit:**

Many people have pointed out that a array might be sufficient. First of all: You might be right and thank you for your comment. My example was highly simplified. At each step I would need to calculate up to ten thousand of new possible nodes and I need to make roughly 1000 iterations. The Idea of only following a couple of nodes (in my example 2 but in my application most likely ~100 or something like *"the best x percent"* was simply to reduce the number of possibilities. I think it is obvious that the problem would otherwise explode quite quickly.

**Edit2:**

seems like there is some confusion about the numbers:
Right now the code runs sequential (no graph, just an array). For every possible new node I calculated a *score* based on some metrics. At the end I select the node which has the highest score and go on with the new iteration.

The idea how to implement it with a graph is the following:
Again for every possible node I calculate the *score* (this is the number over the lines that connect two nodes) but the thing we are interested in is the sum of all these *scores* through the graph which is the number I wrote in the nodes. This means I am interested in the path through the graph which leads to the highest sum of scores.

Comment: " In the next step I only want to consider the two nodes with the highest score," & " I only want to consider these two nodes as my next start point" & "... the previous score 6 nodes are ignored from now on. " ... this sounds to me as if you dont need a tree or graph at all, but just a flat array of the nodes in the current step

Comment: I might be wrong, but consider this simple analogy: You dont need explicitly a graph in your code to traverse a graph, just as you dont need to store an array of numbers from 0 to 100 to write a loop that goes from 0 to 100 ;)

Comment: I think it is better to use a graph, of course in my example from node 7 to the end I would not need one. But let's look at the start. I start with node 3 and then calculate node 6 and 7 and now I want to calculate two nodes based on node 7 but I have two arrays, one with 3 and 6 and one with 3 and 7. So I need to create a second 3, 7 array. Also It is not necessary that I want to follow only 2 branches. Think more of "I would like to follow the 10% of best score"

Comment: I can only comment on your example here, what you really want to do i dont know ;)

Comment: I agree that array is sufficient. Every step needs 8 new nodes and this can be implemented easily by and array.

Comment: I know, I guess my example was to simple :) But at least your comment makes me now thinking about the problem again...

Comment: please don't take the example to serious. In my application every step will create up to 10 thousand new nodes. and I need to make roughly 1000 iterations.

Comment: @user463035818 that's a broken analogy, since all the information for the array is encapsulated in the boundary values `[0, 100)` whereas the same is clearly untrue for the graph. I get what you're saying, but what you're saying seems irrelevant (Boost Graph doesn't only have graph models, but comes with algorithms that are independent of the graph model.)

Comment: @sehe yes `[0,100)` wasnt the best example, my comment wasnt about using Boost Graphs but just about having a graph explicitly in the code. @OP please note that I am rather trying to understand than trying to give advice

Comment: What does "explicitly in the code" even mean? I maintain that having a few of "implicitly related" arrays is still a graph. In the code.

Comment: I'm also quite confused about the "weights" which seem to happen to be equal to the difference between the node "values". Are node values unique? Are the ids values? Are the weights the differences? Etc.